# Is Ubuntu One available for Aptosid or Siduction?

Tags: ubuntu-one, debian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is running Ubuntu One on Debian 'possible'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10271/is-running-ubuntu-one-on-debian-possible)

I'm a happy ubuntuuser since years and i use of course ubuntuone. In my profession I have to work with Microsoft xp and 7, but also with aptosid and siduction (debian-based). I'm very surprised, that I#m not able to install ubuntuone onto the last operatingsystems. Is there any simple way to get rid of this "illness"?